# Animate UIImageView appearing on screen line by line

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, core-animation

I'd like to display a `UIImageView` with some animation and i'm thinking i'd like for it to appear on the screen pixel by pixel moving left to right, line by line. A bit like a printer would print an image.
I haven't got a clue where to start with this.

I was thinking maybe overlay the `UIImageView` with another view that can use animation to become transparent, but how can I make it happen?

Comment: Could you please share a sample animation as close as you want? And if you tried something before please share your code

Comment: When you say line by line, do you mean to have, for example, a 100x100 square come in from a direction with 10 lines at 10x100 or 100x10?

Comment: Actually, I think I mean pixel by pixel rather than line by line. 100x100 would appear in 10x10 squares starting at the top left and drawing the first row 10x10 squares then moving onto second row.

Comment: Think how a printer would print an image.

Comment: I guess I could overlay 100 small `UIView`s then remove them 1 at a time. Seems a bit overkill though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one idea is, we have one view on top of your image, covering it entirely. Let's call this view V. Move that view down by 1 point, so a line of your image is exposed. Then have another view on top of your image, covering it entirely again. Let's call this view H. Then move that view right by 1 point. Now one "pixel" (or rather, a 1x1 point grid) of your image is exposed.

We'll animate H to the right. When it reaches the end, we'll put it back where it started, move V and H down by 1 point, and repeat the process.

Here's something to get you started.

```
extension UIView {

    /**
     - Parameter seconds: the time for one line to reveal
     */
    func scanReveal(seconds: Double) {

        let colour = self.superview?.backgroundColor ?? UIColor.black

        let v = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
        v.backgroundColor = colour
        self.addSubview(v)

        let h = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
        h.backgroundColor = colour
        self.addSubview(h)

        v.frame.origin.y += 1

        // Animate h to the end.
        // When it reaches the end, bring it back, move v and h down by 1 and repeat.

        func move() {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: seconds, animations: {
                h.frame.origin.x = h.bounds.height
            }) { _ in
                h.frame.origin.x = 0
                h.frame.origin.y += 1
                v.frame.origin.y += 1

                if v.frame.origin.y > self.bounds.height {
                    return
                }
                move()
            }
        }
        move()
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like it could work. Much better than splitting the image up which is what i started playing with.